# Spring 2 + Thymeleaf + Validation = Whitelabel Error Page 500

Tags: validation, spring-mvc, groovy, thymeleaf

I'm trying to validate my form input, but after its submit it does not load my controller method, instead it shows a `Whitelabel Error Page` with `Internal Server Error`and status `500` but with the correct validation errors. 
I know it must be a matching issue with the expected parameters of my method, but so far from what I've gathered the rule is simply `BindingResult` then `Model` which I did but it still does not trigger my controller method...

Any thoughts are appreciated.

*Controller-Method, that is not triggered unfortunately:*

```
@Controller
@Validated
public class UserController {
    @PostMapping("/users/add")
    def String usersAdd(@Valid @ModelAttribute("user") User user, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "userAdd"
    } else {
        userRepository.save(user)
        return "usersList"
    }
}
```

*Template-Form:*

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/users/add}" th:object="${user}" method="post">
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{name}">
            <div th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('name')}" th:errors="*{name}">Name Error</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Add</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

*Model-Class:*

```
@Document(collection = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    String id
    @Size(min=3, max=100)
    String name
}
```

Update:

Went debugging and found this part, so it seems it's invoking with the correct parameters. I am new to Spring, so I'm having difficulties thinking about other "newbie"-problems.
in `InvocableHandlerMethod.java` the method `DoInvoke` is called on my `usersAdd` with `Station, BeanPropertyBindingResult, BindingAwareModelMap`.
When Invoking the method it causes a `ConstraintViolationException` which will abort invocation, is this expected?

Comment: Have you tried adding the id in a hidden input?

Comment: I added `<input th:type="hidden" th:field="*{id}" />` to no avail.

Comment: works perfectly with my java code. I didn't try with groovy though.

Comment: You used also the `@Valid` in front of the argument `User user`? Because if I remove it, the method is actually executed, because now no `ConstraintViolationException` is thrown. But unexpectedly `bindingResult.hasErrors()` is false, and since the field is empty it should actually be true instead... guess not there yet.

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out after a looong debug session. The `@Valid` before my `User user` causes a `ConstraintViolationException`, which will, expectedly, abort the invocation of my `usersAdd` because, as expected, the parameter is not valid. 
And the reason for this behaviour was the `@Validated` at the controller class, which I picked up from some tutorial, but when removed everything works and validates as expected. 
I guess I was checking a REST-Tutorial and tried to use their approach... not the best idea ;)

Comment: I totally agree with you. I had same situation.